# Mobile phone not recognizing media queries

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

So I have an interesting predicament, I' working on a responsive site, and when I resize my browser everything works as it should, but when I view the site from my iphone, it's not grabbing the queries from the appropriate media query, which I have defined as:

```
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  rules
}
```

The site is ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev2 Wondering if anyone has come across this before.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might just need to tweak the value. Have you seen this? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: This is also a good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your head to get your mobile device to respect your media queries.

Comment: I too was having trouble getting mobile devices to use the media queries I had set up. This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases with images extending beyond the width of the body or page wrapper in mobile, simply putting

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">`

in the head can adjust the body to be centered.